# Is it bad practice to combine a projects static site with the app?

Tags: architecture, web-development, web-applications, websites, reactjs

We are building a react based web app for a project/potential business and I'm wondering if it's ok to include the static site in the web app code?

I've always had a separate basic html and css code base for the static site but if I included as a couple react components I could re-use a lot of the app styling and code.

I'm just wondering if there is any potential drawbacks from combining them?

Answer (score 1):

If the web app doesn't need to be deployed separatly, then i don't see any reasons that you shouldn't mix them. You might want to separate them if for example this web app will potentially be rebranded and deployed internally in your client's infrastracture.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. We are building the platform as a service so it wouldn't be ever rebranded.